# Getting image from Google User Content

Tags: html, image, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

I am preparing a workflow application where I need to get the images hosted on Google Docs. Such as:

https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0ByLBLyPdn6nqcUJ5YzN2cGYwc0U

or

https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0ByLBLyPdn6nqN1IyZEp5Y2hCdk0&export=download&display=/0ByLBLyPdn6nqN1IyZEp5Y2hCdk0

How can I convert these links in Google Spreadsheets or Google Docs to an image link where I will be able to display them with `<img src=""/>` ?

I hope I am clear enough.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have been looking at images in Google Spreadsheets and have used =image()

The string would be https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=*FILEID*

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it didn't work for me with this link. The formula cannot catch the image with that link.

Comment: Is the image shared?  So that people with the link can view.

Comment: I guess yes because it is not hosted on my account, it is an image that I receive automatically from a form submission.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to see the image you are trying to link to (403 error), but try to use a url for your image that is just the image itself. This will end in .jpg or .png or whatever your image file is. Then use =image("url") in your spreadsheet.